# Does the OSI model apply anywhere else other than computer networking?

Tags: networking, osi

I try to understand the OSI model, more about why it was created and what exactly it tries to achieve.

The Wikipedia page says:

> The Open Systems Interconnection model (OSI model) is a conceptual model that characterises and standardises the communication functions of a telecommunication or computing system without regard to its underlying internal structure and technology. Its goal is the interoperability of diverse communication systems with standard communication protocols.

It emerges from  "the OSI is aimed to characterize and standardize the communication functions of a telecommunication or computing system" that the OSI applies to other things other than computing systems. Can someone provide an example of what other implementations does this model have? Where else can we see those layers?

Comment: *It emerges ... that the OSI applies to other things other than computing systems* You're reading too much into that sentence.  As a practical matter, there are no OSI protocols in use today (except perhaps in a museum).

Comment: How come I have two different questions closed as duplicates of the same question?

Comment: I (and others) are struggling to understand why the linked answer doesn't answer your question.  If you read the history again, I think the answer will come to you.

Comment: "Does the OSI model apply anywhere else other than computer networking?" – Int doesn't even apply *in* computer networking. There are no OSI protocols in use today. IEEE and the Internet won over OSI a long time ago.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - I know that the OSI protocols are not in use. However, the term OSI also refers to a conceptual model, so my question is if this model is applied anywhere else other than computer networking